# Implementing breadcrumbs in Python using Flask?

Tags: python, navigation, flask, breadcrumbs

I want breadcrumbs for navigating my [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) app. An option could be to use a general Python module like [bread.py](http://russell.ballestrini.net/a-homegrown-python-bread-crumb-module/):

> The bread object accepts a url string and grants access to the url
>   crumbs (parts) or url links (list of hrefs to each crumb) .

bread.py generates the breadcrumb from the url path, but I want the elements of the breadcrumb to be the title and link of the previously visited pages.

In Flask, maybe this can be done using a decorator or by extending the `@route` decorator.

Is there a way to have each call of a `route()` add the title and link of the page (defined in the function/class decorated with `@route`) to the breadcrumb? Are there other ways to do it? Any examples of breadcrumbs implemented for Flask?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So you're after "path/history" breadcrumbs, rather than "location" breadcrumbs to use the terminology from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29)?

If you want to have access to the user's history of visited links, then you're going to have to save them in a session. I've had a go at creating a decorator to do this.

`breadcrumb.py`:

```py
import functools
import collections

import flask

BreadCrumb = collections.namedtuple('BreadCrumb', ['path', 'title'])

def breadcrumb(view_title):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            # Put title into flask.g so views have access and
            # don't need to repeat it
            flask.g.title = view_title
            # Also put previous breadcrumbs there, ready for view to use
            session_crumbs = flask.session.setdefault('crumbs', [])
            flask.g.breadcrumbs = []
            for path, title in session_crumbs:
                flask.g.breadcrumbs.append(BreadCrumb(path, title))

            # Call the view
            rv = f(*args, **kwargs)

            # Now add the request path and title for that view
            # to the list of crumbs we store in the session.
            flask.session.modified = True
            session_crumbs.append((flask.request.path, view_title))
            # Only keep most recent crumbs (number should be configurable)
            if len(session_crumbs) > 3:
                session_crumbs.pop(0)

            return rv
        return decorated_function
    return decorator
```

And here's a test application that demonstrates it. Note that I've just used Flask's built-in client side session, you'd probably want to use a more secure server-side session in production, such as [Flask-KVsession](http://flask-kvsession.readthedocs.org/en/0.2/).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import flask
from breadcrumb import breadcrumb

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@breadcrumb('The index page')
def index():
    return flask.render_template('page.html')

@app.route('/a')
@breadcrumb('Aardvark')
def pagea():
    return flask.render_template('page.html')

@app.route('/b')
@breadcrumb('Banana')
def pageb():
    return flask.render_template('page.html')

@app.route('/c')
@breadcrumb('Chimp')
def pagec():
    return flask.render_template('page.html')

@app.route('/d')
@breadcrumb('Donkey')
def paged():
    return flask.render_template('page.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = '83cf5ca3-b1ee-41bb-b7a8-7a56c906b05f'
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And here's the contents of `templates/page.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>{{ g.title }}</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ g.title }}</h1>
        <p>Breadcrumbs:
        {% for crumb in g.breadcrumbs %}
            <a href="{{ crumb.path }}">{{ crumb.title }}</a>
            {% if not loop.last %}&raquo;{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>What next?</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/a">Aardvark</a>?</li>
            <li><a href="/b">Banana</a>?</li>
            <li><a href="/c">Chimp</a>?</li>
            <li><a href="/d">Donkey</a>?</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is awesome but what if you are trying to do the 'location' based crumbs? could you also add an answer for that? i would think it would be much easier.

Comment: @chrisckso: I think 'location' based crumbs is what [bread.py](http://russell.ballestrini.net/a-homegrown-python-bread-crumb-module/) (as mentioned in [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13444666/445073)) does? Have you tried that?

Comment: yes I looked at it but am not a fan of it just pulling off the url as I would like to customize what the words are. i'm looking for the simplest way to do a decorator like @breadtrail(['Crumb A', url_for('...)], ['Crumb B', url_for('...)]) and always pass a breadtrail var filled with that data to jinja without having to type breadtrail=breadtrail for every route.

Comment: Thanks a lot Day for your post! I know this is an old thread but I was wondering how to have a variable in the breadcrumb?

e.g. @app.route(/products/)

I would like to have the breadcrumb named based on the variable in the URL but I have no idea how to achieve that? Can anyone help.

Thanks again

Comment: @col slade: Flask-Breadcrumbs (https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Breadcrumbs/) appears to offer just that capability. Not tried it myself yet, but about to...

Answer (score 0):

i was trying to use the breadcrumb.py , but i was need to check:

- if the new item "item = (flask.request.path, view title) " is already exist in the session crumbs, then i will delete all other items frome the index to the end, i do this for Avoid repetition in my session crumds.

  ```
           flask.session.modified = True
           item = (flask.request.path, view_title)
           try:
               if not item in session_crumbs:
                   session_crumbs.append(item)
               else:
                   index = session_crumbs.index(item)

                   session_crumbs = session_crumbs[:index+1]

           except:
               pass

           return rv
       return decorated_function
   return decorator
  ```